# Error while Upgrading gradle from version 4 to version 5 | Gradle sourceSets

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

After upgrading from gradle 4 to gradle 5 I am getting error and unable to understand what is expected compatible changes are required.[image: Error in sourceSers]

My project is multi modules and having same issue with other build files as well.
[image]

Comment: [Please don't share screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You can try looking through the upgrade notes https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html

Comment: Yeh i saw this document but the required fix was not clear. Thanks for sharing